# Git cannot merge when using eclipse with multiple folders of stuff being changed

Tags: eclipse, git

I am trying to use Git with a Minecraft Coder Pack but the problem is when another developer and I are collaborating and pushing code to Git, we run into a merging conflict.

[image: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/317738157309427722/595836751809871932/unknown.png]

I uploaded my remote repo the entire contents of the folder and a lot of the folders were there for the installation process but I am not sure which ones.
https://gyazo.com/c0f7a41aeb356b05844edd65a46a5bad

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with upload, but, regarding [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), with download.

That download cannot complete because your current local working tree (on your PC) has files with unresolved merges (merge markers) in them.

Do a `git status` to list them, resolve those merge conflicts (locally), add and commit.

Then, and only then, try your `git pull` again.

Comment: How would you resolve the conflicts? Would you use git merge tool because I am having trouble resolving the conflicts.

Comment: @MrNewbieCoder If you can open them with VSCode, that editor has great Git support and can help vizualising merge conflicts.

Comment: Right now the conflict is not with any of the code but with this stuff which I am not sure where or what it means. I'm assuming this is what happens in the background when Eclipse saves the files. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/317738157309427722/595847601354571776/unknown.png

Comment: @MrNewbieCoder I suppose: I am not familiar with that kind of conflict though.